# Посчитать отношение (пропорция) на Verilog

Tags: verilog

*Имеется отрезок, предположительно, длиной 250 единиц **(1)**. На нем расположена точка на метке 180.*
*В реальности длина отрезка 224 единицы **(2)**.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значение искомой точки должно быть пропорционально 180, при длине отрезка 250, и равно в данном случае 161 на отрезке, длиной 224. По сути расчет сводится к пропорции: **(224 * 180) / 250**.

```
module WorkController(
// DATA IN
input wire [15:0] i_Input_1_SegmentLength,  // 250 - длина отрезка 1
input wire [15:0] i_Input_2_SegmentLength,  // 224 - длина отрезка 2
input wire [15:0] i_InputPointPosition,     // 180 - положение точки на отрезке 1
// DATA OUT
output reg [15:0] o_OutputPointPosition);   // ? - результат расчета - положение точки на отрезке 2
//o_OutputPointPosition  должен быть равен  161;
endmodule
```

Если я пишу в лоб вот так: `assign o_OutputPointPosition = (i_Input_2_SegmentLength * i_InputPointPosition) / i_Input_1_SegmentLength;`, то это занимает от 300-500 LE, что не допустимо для простенького камня EPM240 на 240LE, на котором хотелось бы это реализовать. Можно пожертвовать точностью. Может быть существуют побитовые хитрости для подобных задач или расчет в несколько шагов?
**Как средствами Verilog оптимально рассчитать положение точки на отрезке (2) с некоторым минимально возможным округлением? Как получить значение 161?** *Желательно с примером кода.*

Comment: @Kromster, В оптимизации. Если я пишу в лоб вот так: `assign o_OutputPointPosition = (i_Input_2_SegmentLength * i_InputPointPosition) / i_Input_1_SegmentLength;` , то это занимает около 300LE, что не допустимо для EPM240, на котором хотелось бы это реализовать. Можно пожертвовать точностью, главное оптимизировать. Может быть существуют побитовые хитрости для таких задач или расчет в несколько шагов...

Comment: В вопросе часть кода, все значения 15-тибитные

Comment: Я так понимаю, что не существует (по крайней мере в ответах) специальных алгоритмов для осуществления подобных операций без прибегания к умножению и делению. Думаю, придется ставить на печатную плату дополнительный простой микроконтроллер, который и будет заниматься арифметикой и заодно работой с UART, что значительно разгрузит EPM240. Спасибо за комментарии. Буду рад новым, если появятся.